# ng-disabled directive doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angular controller with the following html.  This is for pagination.

```
<li class="{{(first) ? 'disabled' : ''}}">
    <a href="" ng-click="pageChange('first')" ng-disabled="first">First</a>
</li>
```

The class is applied to the li, but ng-click is not disabled on the anchor.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable an `a` element.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html:

> 4.13 Disabled elements
>
> An element is said to be actually disabled if it falls into one of the following categories:
>
> button elements that are disabled
>
> input elements that are disabled
>
> select elements that are disabled
>
> textarea elements that are disabled
>
> optgroup elements that have a disabled attribute
>
> option elements that are disabled
>
> fieldset elements that have a disabled attribute

Most likely you will want to change the `a` element to a `button` and style it to look like a link.

This is a fiddle demonstrating: http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/q8r4e/

The fiddle is not mine, just googled for one.

If it's in bootstrap,

```
<button type="button" ng-click="pageChange('first')" ng-disabled="first" class="btn btn-link">First</button>
```

If you just want to prevent the function from firing in the view:

```
<a href="" ng-click="!first && pageChange('first')">
```

Comment: Originally it was a span.  Still didn't work.  It's in a bootstrap pagination ul.

Comment: A span is still not in the list I just gave you of elements that can be disabled.

Comment: If it's in bootstrap, `<button type="button" ng-click="pageChange('first')" ng-disabled="first" class="btn btn-link">First</button>`

Comment: Apologies, I was under the impression that ng-disabled would disable ng-click regardless of whether the element could have a valid disabled attribute.  I'll just handle it in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

to disable a element you need to use css

```
.active {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```

use ng-class to apply it

Answer (score 0):

This works to me.

```
a[disabled="disabled"] {
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;
}
```